# Trigger windows updates from command line (wuauclt.exe alternative)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

So, I've had a script for a while that would trigger windows 7 "windows update" with `wuauclt.exe /updatenow` (see [this](http://pauby.com/blog/windows-update-agent-utility-wuauclt-exe/) article for wuauclt.exe flags). In windows 10, this seems to not exist (or do anything that I can tell).

Does anyone know the alternative(s) to force windows 10 to go get it's updates (in my case from a WSUS server)?

*What I have found so far:*

I've found using `control.exe /name Microsoft.WindowsUpdate` pulls up the windows update page now located in the settings panel to then manually click "check for updates".  The purpose of this being in a script of course to automate this process. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3iovtx/launch_windows_update_from_command_line/)

I did find a vbscript that would trigger updates (though I am  still hopeful that a command line function still exists). Below is the two relevant lines that you need. [Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/wuaucltexe-detectnow-command-doesnt-work-in/43dc5e35-6efa-432e-8256-d30096678849?auth=1)

```
Set automaticUpdates = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate")
automaticUpdates.DetectNow()
```

Comment: You really have not accurately described what happens when you execute the Windows Update Agent from the cmd line.

Comment: Nothing seems to happen.  I can pull up windows update manually and it does not search or anything else.  /detectnow, /updatenow, etc. do not do anything.  I get no error message, but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

The `wuauclt.exe` executable does exist.
 try `CD C:\Windows\System32` now you can use `wuauclt.exe /detectnow /updatenow`

Comment: System32 should be in the path by default.  So it should find it already.

Comment: I don't see any documentation on there being an `/updatenow` option.

Comment: It appears to be undocumented, it does exists. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/windows-10-upgrade/2d312330-abe9-4153-a009-321af64c55b6